# Simplifying sums of symbolic min terms

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm new to SymPy, so this might actually be easy, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation that quite matched. I'm trying to simplify the following expression:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> i, N = symbols('i N', integer=True, negative=False)
>>> summation(Min(N-8*i, 8), (i, 0, ceiling(N/8)-1)).simplify()
Sum(Min(8, N - 8*i), (i, 0, ceiling(N/8) - 1))
```

This could simplify to just `N` (and is true in general for a positive `k`, in place of `8`). Is there some way I can get this to happen?